OpenRewrite - rewrite for rewriting OpenRewrite 7 recipe to OpenRewrite 8 recipe
OpenRewrite provides an extensive guide: Rewrite 7 to 8 migration for rewriting your recipes. This is fine and all, but what you really expect from OpenRewrite is a rewrite recipe for this... I haven't been able to find this, anyone else (official or community)?
I have tried to find information about this at docs.openrewrite.org without success...

We had migration recipes to go from Rewrite 7 to Rewrite 8 for a while, but as it's been a year and those were hard to maintain, we removed those recipes and references to them. You could still try to run older versions of Rewrite to migrate from 7 to 8, but your mileage may very: they are not supported these days.
I hope this context helps you in some way still, even if the present day absence of recipes might be disappointing.
